# How best to test and unwrap std::optional in an if statement

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I have multiple functions that return a `std::optional<T>`. Here's an example for a made-up type `MyType`:

```
struct MyType {
    // ...
}

std::optional<MyType> calculateOptional() {
    // ... lengthy calculation

    if (success) {
        return MyType(/* etc */);
    }

    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Let's assume these functions are costly to run and I want to avoid calling them more than once.

When calling them I want to immediately test the optional, and if it does contain a value, I want to use it immediately and never again. In Swift, for example, I can use the standard `if-let` statement:

```
if let result = calculateOptional() {
    // Use result var
}
```

I would like to replicate this test-and-unwrap behavior in C++, while keeping the code as clean as possible at the point of use. For example, the obvious simple solution (to me at least) would be:

```
if (auto result = calculateOptional()) {
    MyType result_unwrapped = *result;
    // Use result_unwrapped var
}
```

But you have to unwrap inside the `if`, or use `*result` everywhere, which you don't have to do with Swift.

My only solution so far that genuinely gets close to the look and feel of Swift is:

```
template<typename T> bool optionalTestUnwrap(std::optional<T> opt, T& value) {
    if (!opt.has_value()) { return false; }
    value = *opt;
    return true;
}

#define ifopt(var, opt) if (typename decltype((opt))::value_type (var); optionalTestUnwrap((opt), (var)))

ifopt (result, calculateOptional()) {
    // Use result var
}
```

...but I'm also not a big fan of the use of a macro to replace a normal `if` statement.

Comment: Wouldn't the `obvious simple solution` that you've posted be actually good? It's still concise, does not introduce macros, and explicitly states what you want, what might be better from maintainability perspective.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski it is good, I agree, just not the best if you have many optionals to unwrap and want to simplify your code with regards to the * unwrapping

Comment: @Alex: "*For example, the obvious simple solution*" Doesn't that copy the object? Wouldn't using `*result` not be better on performance grounds, if `MyType` is of some size/complexity?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes. A better option would be `auto& result = *resultOpt;` as @Barry wrote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I would just do:

```
if (auto result = calculateOptional()) {
    // use *result
}
```

with a second best of giving the optional an ugly name and making a nicer-named alias for it:

```
if (auto resultOpt = calculateOptional()) {
    auto& result = *resultOpt;
    // use result
}
```

I think this is good enough. It's a great use-case for intentionally shadowing an outer-scope name (i.e. naming both the `optional` and the inner alias `result`), but I don't think we need to go crazy here. Even using `*result` isn't a big problem - the type system will likely catch all misuses.

---

If we really want to go in on Swift, the macro you're using requires default construction - and it's not really necessary. We can do a little bit better with (ideally `__opt` is replaced by a mechanism that selects a unique name, e.g. concatenating with `__LINE__`):

```
#define if_let(name, expr)              \
    if (auto __opt = expr)              \
        if (auto& name = *__opt; false) {} else
```

As in:

```
if_let(result, calculateOptional()) {
    // use result
} else {
    // we didn't get a result
}
```

This doesn't have any extra overhead or requirements. But it's kind of ridiculous, has its own problems, and doesn't seem worthwhile. But if we're just having fun, this works.

Comment: this macro is kind of hilarious.

Comment: That `if false else` is quite funny. Ok, I'll use the `*result` option. But out of curiosity, what `own problems` does your macro have, besides possible name collisions?

Comment: @Barry Maybe one could let the user provide the whole declaration for name (so replace `auto& name` by `name` in the macro). Then so stuff like `int val = 0; if_let(val, get_maybe_int()) ;` or `if_let(arr[0], get_maybe_val()); ` is possible and one can also stay `const`- correct.

Comment: @Barry what are some of the problems you refer to when saying "has its own problems"? other than creating a new variable and having an extra if

Answer (score 0):

Another simple and potentially safer one:

`#define unwrap(x, val, block) if (auto opt_##x = val) { auto &x = opt_##x; block }`

Usage:

```
unwrap(result, calculateOptional(), {
  // use result
});
```

Comment: I think in this variant, safe unwrap by * in the if block would be possible; could you also write a variant with an else block (e.g. usable for error handling)?

Comment: Safe as much a macro can be safe. So not much at all.

Comment: there's a few ways to go about it, make else another param for example `#define unwrap_else(x, val, block, elseBlock) if (auto opt_##x = val) { auto &x = opt_##x; block } else { elseBlock }`

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the optional in an own type with implicit conversion to the type and explicit to `bool`. Sorry I haven't tested this so far but I think it should work.

```
template<class T>
struct opt {
    std::optional<T> _optional; // public so it stays an aggregate, probably writing constructors is better

    explicit bool() const {
        return _optional.has_value();
    }

    T&() {
        return *_optional;
    }

    const T&() const {
         return *_optional;
    }

    T&&() && { // Let's be fancy
         return std::move(*optional);
    }
}

opt<int> blub(bool val) {
    return val ? opt<int>{0} : opt<int>{std::nullopt};
}

int main() {
    if(auto x = blub(val)) { // I hope this works as I think it does
        int y = x+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The implicit conversion isn't enough for all cases. E.g. if `auto x = blub()` returned `opt<std::string>` and you wanted `x.size()`.

Answer (score -1):

If `calculateOptional()` returns a `std::pair<bool sucess, T result>` or can be converted in one, you can use the following construct:

```
if (auto [s, result] = calculatePair(); s) {

} else {

}
```

or you use exceptions; `(...)` catches all exceptions

```
try {
    auto result = calculate();

} catch (...) {

}
```

but you can be more specific

```
try {
    auto result = calculate();

} catch (nosuccess) {

}
```

Answer (score -2):

This could be a clean way, inspired by all other answers in this post:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::pair<bool, T> _unwrap(const std::optional<T> &val) {
    return { val.has_value(), *val };
}

#define unwrap(x, val) const auto &[_##x, x] = _unwrap(val); (_##x)
```

Usage:

```
if (unwrap(result, calculateOptional())) {
  // result is now equivalent to *calculateOptional()
}
```

Pros:

- You don't mess with the if statement
- It maintains a method-like feel to it
- You can still add more conditions to the right of the if statement

Cons:

- Read-only but then again optionals already are

Happy to hear of any issues/fixes you guys might think there might be with this solution.

Comment: If the `optional` you pass to `_unwrap` is not engaged, then `*val` will not be a reference to an object. And you can't copy from that.

Comment: @NicolBolas considering this example with a disengaged optional: `std::optional<int> a; if (unwrap(A, a)) { printf("%i", A); } else { printf("no"); }` a is disengaged (if I'm not wrong) and it doesn't matter that *a has undefined behavior because it gets kicked to the else scope, I get it that you can still access the variable but that's something you can still do with normal disengaged optional c++ unwrapping.

Comment: The `pair` contains a `T`, not a `T&`. Therefore, that `T` must be constructed. `*val` returns a `T&`, which is used to initialize the `T` in the `pair`. That `T` is therefore initialized by copying from `*val`'s `T&`. Since `*val` doesn't refer to an object, you will be copying from something that doesn't exist.